# Traefik config with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to use traefik in my docker-compose file. My php app is listening on port 8000

```
version: '3'

services:
    traefik:
        image: traefik:1.7.4
        container_name: traefik-${PROJECT_NAME}
        ports:
            - ${TRAEFIK_PORT}:80
            - ${TRAEFIK_PORT_HTTPS}:443
            - ${TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_PORT}:8080
        volumes:
            - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        networks:
            - webgateway

    php-fpm:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-php
        container_name: php-fpm-${PROJECT_NAME}
        ports:
            - 8000
        working_dir: /var/www/html/
        volumes:
            - ../app:/var/www/html
        tty: true
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh
        networks:
            - traefik

networks:
    webgateway:
        driver: bridge
    traefik:
        external:
            name: traefik_webgateway

volumes:
    data-volume: {}
```

Trefik watch every container

```
[docker]
domain = "local"
watch = true
```

All container appear in Traefik dashboard but frontend Host do not match with IP address. I can't access the app.

But when I go directly through the container IP address, it works.

Did I missed something in the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. I have added host name in my `/etc/hosts` file. 
Works fine with that